# Statistical method for small data in percentage

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, small-sample

I have 5 measurements for 2 groups, and this measurements are in percentages. I want to compare if the percentage of Group A is different from the percentage of Group B.

I thought about Mann-Whitney or t-test, but the data is just too small to evaluate if the distribution is normal or not.

What statistical test can I use?

Comment: Please clarify what a "percentage" is.  If it's one count divided by a total, then you need to analyze the counts themselves.  Otherwise, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: it is one count divided by a total, but I only have access to the percentage data

Comment: Unless all the measurements in one group exceed all the measurements in another group, it will be difficult to support any definite conclusion about a difference.  (This is essentially the result of a two-sided MW test conducted at a $6.25\%$ significance level--it's the best you can get.)